# mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax. I cant find the fix for my syntax. TY

Tags: python, mysql, csv, import, mysql-connector

```
import csv

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
    host='localhost',
    user= 'root',
    passwd='xxx',
    db='xxx',
    auth_plugin='mysql_native_password')

cursor = mydb.cursor()
s = open('uniprot_entries_results.csv', mode='r', encoding='utf-8').read()
open('uniprot_entries_results.csv', mode='w', encoding='utf-8').write(s)
print(s)

with open('uniprot_entries_results.csv') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter='\t')
    sql = """INSERT INTO target_information (yourlist:M20200509A94466D2655679D1FD8953E075198DA8AF037EL, Entry, Entry_name, Status, Protein_names, Gene_names, Organism, Length) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"""
    cursor.executemany(sql, csv_reader)
    mydb.commit()


mydb.close()
```

> Error:mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ':M20200509A94466D2655679D1FD8953E075198DA8AF037EL, Entry, Entry_name, Status, Pr' at line 1

Comment: import mysql.connector got cut off in the first line but thats not the problem :)

Comment: Is there really a column on this table called `yourlist:M20200509A94466D2655679D1FD8953E075198DA8AF037EL` I HOPE NOT

Comment: yes there is xD

Comment: ty it works with the " ` ` "